# Resolve domain script

Tags: bash, shell-script, hosts

How to make it work?

---

**Script 1:** (This does not work)

```
host=www.example.com
ip=$(getent hosts | grep $host | awk '{ print $1}')
echo $ip
```

**Script 2:** (This does not work)

```
host=www.example.com
ip=$(getent hosts $host | awk '{ print $1}') 
echo $ip
```

**Script 3:** (It works, but I need to use a variable...)

```
ip=$(getent hosts www.example.com | awk '{ print $1}') 
echo $ip
```

I need to take the appropriate hosts file IP, depending on the variable.

---

**Hosts:** (etc/hosts)

```
 127.0.0.1  localhost
 1.1.1.1  www.example.com
```

Comment: For each "does not work" please would you show what happens on your system, and contrast that with what you expect to happen.

Answer (score 2):

1. What you have there should work, there's no reason why it shouldn't.  It certainly works on my system.
2. you don't need the `grep`.  The following will work:

`ip=$(getent hosts "$host" | awk '{ print $1}')`

Comment: Grepping will treat the dots as RE metacharacters, so there could be false positives. Apart from that, I don't see why it wouldn't be working for the OP either.

Comment: Your version does not work, I outputs an empty string. If I do so:
`ip=$(getent hosts www.example.com | awk '{ print $1}')`
`echo $ip`
It works, but I need to use a variable...

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing the two different result sets that can be obtained with `getent hosts`.

1. `getent hosts` will return a result broadly equivalent to `cat /etc/hosts`
2. `getent hosts TARGET` will use the `hosts` entry in `/etc/nsswitch.conf` to lookup one or more host databases for `TARGET`, returning the first match it finds

Script 1 will look up `host` only from `/etc/hosts`. It can also be slightly shortened:

```
host=www.example.com
ip=$(getent hosts | awk '/'"$host"'/ {print $1; exit}')
echo $ip
```

Scripts 2 and 3 will search `/etc/hosts` and probably DNS too. It's not clear to me where you are putting `'` or `"` so that your third script fails to work.

Comment: I need to take the appropriate hosts file IP, depending on the variable. Your script is not working.

Comment: @J.Doy please demonstrate what you mean by "not working" as your scripts (and therefore my adaptation) all give me the expected output. Ideally, edit your question to provide this information.